# What is the algorithm that you use to populate a Type-3 SCD?

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, talend

A bit new here, but here goes.  What is the algorithm that you use to populate a Type-3 SCD?  I have fact tables and dimension tables setup already, and have done this already through TOS in talend, but need the code.  Using MySQL.  Any kind of general idea or even reference to the right way to go about this is appreciated.  Also any documentation reference is also welcome.

Comment: Read what SCD Type 3 is and implement that using SQL. There are many online documentation explaining how to implement SCD Type 3 dimensions

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to locate online a bunch of places and all I get is an explanation of what the type 3 is.  I guess what I am looking for a=is an example of the code used is, like i said I have made it work using TOS, but would like to see the code.  Thanks

Comment: each vendor use different code or programming languages to achieve this, if you understand SCD logic you can write code by yourself. talend uses java based transformation stage to achieve this, you can check their [source code here](https://github.com/Talend/tsf) to copy logic if you don't want to work on one by yourself.

Comment: Furthermore you can open your Talend Job and look at the Code-Tab (ctrl+g) to see the actual Java code instead of looking at the generator code.

Answer (score 1):

Well i guess this is what you are looking for.
eg we have a salesperson dimension table and we need to change its territory using `SCD Type-3`

**Step-1**

Add Column using ALTER Table Statement

`ALTER TABLE SalesPersonTable ADD old_territory datatype`

old_territory is added`

**Step-2**

Rename previous Column territory to new_territory

`ALTER TABLE SalesPersonTable CHANGE territory new_territory datatype`

**Step-3**

Update the affected SalesPerson data

`UPDATE SalesPersonTable SET old_territory = new_territory WHERE SalesPersonKey=YourKeyHere`

**Step-4**

Update the new_territory now

`UPDATE SalesPersonTable SET new_territory = 'New Territory' WHERE SalesPersonKey=YourKeyHere`

Now you can see here that there is nothing like algorithm here. There are just simple steps to follow. you can write your own procedures to make this. Good Luck with That.